# Passing a struct to a callback function

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I'm trying to pass a struct to a callback function that runs when the combobox is changed, here's my code:

```
static struct parameters changed_set_parameters;

changed_set_parameters.set_combo = set_combo;

gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (set_combo), "changed",GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(set_changed), &changed_set_parameters);
```

Here's the function:

```
void set_changed(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params) {
    g_print ("%s\n",gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text ((GtkComboBoxText *)((struct parameters *) callback_params)->set_combo));
}
```

Here's what I get:

```
gtk_signal_handlers.h:7:98: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
       g_print ("%s\n",gtk_combo_box_text_get_active_text ((GtkComboBoxText *)((struct parameters *) callback_params)->set_combo));
```

I have almost the same code in another  application and it's running just fine

Comment: struct parameters , where is the definition? is its scope correct ?

Comment: Why does the error message omit the cast `(GtkComboBoxText *)` but not the cast `(struct parameters *)`?

Comment: weather, that was an old output, I've copied the most recent message
kkk ugh, it was a scope problem, can't believe I still make these mistakes :(  
thanks

Comment: Even the best of us repeat basic mistakes every once in a while :)

Answer (score 0):

> `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`

The dereferencing operator here is `->`, the dereferenced pointer is `((struct parameters *) callback_params)`, its type is `struct parameters *`, `set_combo` is a member of `struct parameters`, thus the definition of `struct parameters` must be out of scope here.